How to fix error "java/sql/DriverManager" in KMP?
I'm developing a desktop app than manages a PostgresSQL database using Compose Multiplatform.
When I run the app with IntelliJ it works fine, but when I generate an installer with ./gradlew packageMsi and install it on my pc, I get this error in a dialog box:
java/sql/DriverManager


This is my code:
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        val connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_database",
                "postgres",
                "12345")

        Text(connection.isvalid(1000))
    }
}

I tried just getting the available drivers and still the same error, so I'm guessing the problem is not with postgres drivers.
